# Asp.net auth0 and mfa

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

Im working on an old solution that contain a lots of Apps using asp.net webforms using visual studio 2013 in vb and im using simple authenication way with matching the adusername and the users data from a table in the database.

My question can asp.net Apps accept adding auth0 and mfa ? Because I made a search on internet and I saw most of the result is .net core so im wondering if there is a way to do that for asp.net and it won't complicate things or its a waste of time? Thank you in advance

I looked on Google and most of the result is in .net core and im using asp.net webforms projects

Comment: Yes it can be done. As you said there are a lot of examples out there. Just adjust one of them to webforms, like this one: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/two-factor-authentication-using-google-authenticator-in-asp-net-mvc/